# is there any way to create an animation (gganimate) with ranges as transition times?

Tags: r, ggplot2, gganimate

Is there any way to make gganimate work for transition times that are ranges of years? In my data I have three time points, two of which are ranges as shown below.

data:

```
Year   rate   group
2012-2014   7   Other CT, White 
2015-2017   11  Other CT, White 
2018    3   Fairfield, Black    
2018    2   Fairfield, Hispanic
```

here's an example of the code for the ggplot that I'd like to animate

```
data %>% ggplot(aes(y = rate, x = group)) +
  geom_col() +
  coord_flip() +
  labs(title = "Year: {frame_time}") +
  transition_time(Year)
```

when I enter the transition time as "Year" I get an error because my Year variable is a character to accommodate the ranges. This is the error I get:

```
Error: time data must either be integer, numeric, POSIXct, Date, difftime, orhms
```

is there anything I can do to bypass this error and continue with the ranges as they are?

Comment: Make a new column with year bins (e.g. `ggplot2::cut_interval`) then use that variable in `transition_time`?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I'd suggest either using `transition_manual` and treat the years like categories (which loses a smooth transition), or convert the year range to numbers.

```
library(tidyverse); library(gganimate)
df1 <- tribble(~Year, ~rate, ~group,
               "2012-2014", 7, "grp1",
               "2015-2017", 11, "grp1",
               "2018", 3, "grp1")
```

First approach, keeping Year as-is as character:

```
df1 %>% 
  ggplot(aes(y = rate, x = group)) +
  geom_col() +
  coord_flip() +
  labs(title = "Year: {current_frame}") +
  transition_manual(Year)
```

[image]

Second approach, converting year to numeric. In this case, I just used the first year, but you could alternatively assign the value to the average year, or add rows with the value for each year in the range.

```
df1 %>% 
  mutate(Year_numeric = parse_number(Year)) %>%
  ggplot(aes(y = rate, x = group)) +
  geom_col() +
  coord_flip() +
  labs(title = "Year: {round(frame_time)}") +
  transition_time(Year_numeric)
```

[image]

Finally, if you want to represent all the ranged years at the given level, you can create rows for all the component years. But this takes some elbow grease:

```
df1 %>% 
  # For ranged years, find how many in range:
  mutate(year_num = 1 + if_else(Year %>% str_detect("-"), 
                            str_sub(Year, start = 6) %>% as.numeric() - 
                              str_sub(Year, end = 4) %>% as.numeric(), 
                            0)) %>%
  # ... and use that to make a row for each year in the range
  tidyr::uncount(year_num) %>%
  group_by(Year) %>%
  mutate(Year2 = str_sub(Year, end = 4) %>% as.numeric() + 
                 row_number() - 1) %>%
  ungroup() %>%

# FYI at this point it looks like:
# A tibble: 7 x 4
#  Year       rate group Year2
#  <chr>     <dbl> <chr> <dbl>
#1 2012-2014     7 grp1   2012
#2 2012-2014     7 grp1   2013
#3 2012-2014     7 grp1   2014
#4 2015-2017    11 grp1   2015
#5 2015-2017    11 grp1   2016
#6 2015-2017    11 grp1   2017
#7 2018          3 grp1   2018

ggplot(aes(y = rate, x = group)) +
  geom_col() +
  coord_flip() +
  labs(title = "Year: {round(frame_time)}") +
  transition_time(Year2)
```

[image]

Comment: thank you so much. the first approach you offered is exactly what I was looking for!